# How to connect to SQL Server using ADO.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, ado.net

This is the first time I'm designing a web site. I'm having problem on connecting to my database. None of buttons work on pages. The most important one is Register button. I fill the form correctly but when I press Register button it doesn't register the new user into database. It even doesn't show any error message which I've considered. For example, it doesn't show that You've registered before or Your registration wasn't successful. No error message and no new record in my database. I've removed the captcha code because I thought that may cause problem.Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class SignUp : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strname = Cache["TF"] as string;
        if (strname != null)
        {
            (Master.FindControl("Lozv") as Label).Text = strname;
            (Master.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton).Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            (Master.FindControl("Lozv") as Label).Text = "Guest";
            (Master.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton).Visible = false;
        }

    }

    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string username = txtboxUser.Text;
        SqlConnection sqlc = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Database=LDatabase; Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT dbo.CheckUserName(@UN)");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UN", txtboxUser.Text);
        sqlc.Open();
        Boolean User = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        sqlc.Close();

        if (User == false) ////////////// if user name is not in DB//////////////
        {
            SqlConnection sqlca = new SqlConnection();
            sqlca.ConnectionString = "data source=. ; database=LDatabase ; integrated security=true";
            SqlCommand cmda = new SqlCommand();
            cmda.Connection = sqlca;
            cmda.CommandText = "INSERT INTO User_Pass values(@UserName,@Pass,@Name,@LastName,@Email,@Date,@Sex,'0')";
            cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtboxUser.Text);
            cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", txtboxPass.Text);
            cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtboxName.Text);
            cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtboxSurname.Text);
            cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtboxEmail.Text);
            cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
            cmda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sex", rbtnGender.SelectedValue.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@manager", "No");

            sqlca.Open();
            int n= cmda.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (n <= 0)
                LMsg.Text = "Your registration wasn't successful";
            else
            {
                txtboxName.Text = "";
                txtboxSurname.Text = "";
                txtboxUser.Text = "";
                txtboxPass.Text = "";
                txtboxRePass.Text = "";
                txtboxEmail.Text = "";
                rbtnGender.SelectedIndex = -1;
                LMsg.Text = "You registered successfully.";
            }
            sqlca.Close();
        }

        else  //////////////if user name is in db//////////////
        {
            LMsg.Text = "This username has already registered.";
        }
    }
}
```

Does Captcha have anything to do with this type of problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First question:  are you sure your `Button1_Click1` code is even being executed?

Comment: Are you able to step through the Button1_Click1-method by setting a break point on its first line?

Comment: Looks like your connection string inside the new SqlConnection("connectionString") constructor may not be valid.  I haven't seen "Data Source=.;" before.  Don't you need an actual named data source on the system?

Comment: No I'm not. I think it doesn't but I couldn't find the reason.

Comment: @Eric `Data Source=.;` is the same as `Data Source=localhost;`

Comment: @Eric Would you explain? What do you mean by actual named data source?

Comment: @user3050120 Please provide the markup for the button, what does it look like? `<asp:Button.....`

Comment: @cederlof I think I tried once but couldn't find the problem. I'm more familiar to C++ I guess that's why. By first line you meant Button1 function right?

Comment: By a named data source, I mean an actual ODBC data source created via the ODBC Data Source Administrator dialog.  However, per @cederlof's comment, you should be OK as is.  That is not the problem.

Comment: @cederlof Do you mean this: <asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Height="26px" Text="register"
                        Width="88px"/>

Comment: @user3050120 Yes, where do you "bind" the button to the method? For example, inside the button-tag, add: `Click="Button1_Click1"`

Answer (score 0):

Put your button like this in the aspx-markup:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRegister" runat="server" Click="Button1_Click1" Height="26px" Text="register" Width="88px"/>
```

It should trigger the method.

Edit: Or bind the event in the Page_Load method (remove the Click-attribute from the button first - from my previous example above).

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnRegister.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click1);
    string strname = Cache["TF"] as string;
    [...]
```

Comment: OK. Thanks. Let me try it and I'll tell you the result.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line `string username = txtboxUser.Text;`. Is it not being hit when you debug? Put a breakpoint also in the top of Page_Load-method, and confirm it is being hit upon loading the page.

Comment: I put breakpoint on the line string username = txtboxUser.Text; I debug the website and I press register but it doesn't go the breakpoint. When I debug on C++ it prompts on breakpoints when it should, is it the same story?

Comment: Yes, it should be stopped at the breakpoint. So it does get hit inside Page_Load?

Comment: Yes it does get hit inside page load. When I press F10 it comes to the end of Paga_Load function then the yellow pointer disappears.

Comment: @user3050120 Ok, let's try another method. See updated answer.

Comment: I had made some changes to the button. I notices my code are outside of btnregister function. I'm getting on some bugs now.

Comment: Thank you everyone my problem solved. There were some bugs and some conceptual mistakes.